# BLOB randomly returned as LOB and Buffer

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

It seems that oracledb is not consistent in how it retrieves BLOB data from the database, LOB vs Buffer

When using oracledb 3.0.1 with nodejs to retrieve a blob from Oracle via a select statement, sometimes the data is retrieved as a LOB and sometimes as a Buffer.  I need for it to be consistently retrieved as a LOB.

```
    let connection = null;

    const connectionAttributes = {
        user: process.env.NODE_OCO_DB_USER,
        password: process.env.NODE_OCO_DB_PASSWORD,
        connectString:  `${process.env.NODE_OCO_DB_HOST}:${process.env.NODE_OCO_DB_PORT}/${process.env.NODE_OCO_DB_SID}`
    };

    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(connectionAttributes);

    const sql = `
                    SELECT 
                        file_size, file_name, file_content 
                    FROM 
                        ocoadmin.oco_level1_attachment 
                    WHERE 
                        pk_id = :pk_id 
                `;

    const bindParams = { 
        pk_id: req.params.attachmentId,
    }

    const result = await connection.execute(sql, bindParams);

    if (result.rows.length === 0) {
        console.error('Error getting row ' + req.params.attachmentId); 
        throw new Error('Error getting row ' + req.params.attachmentId);
    }

    const fileSize = result.rows[0][0];
    const fileName = result.rows[0][1];
    const blob = result.rows[0][2];
```

It is difficult to handle the blob because sometimes it is returned as a buffer and other times as a LOB, as shown below.

Any idea how to have it always returned as one of the other, preferably as a LOB.

**Sometimes the blob is provided as a Buffer:**

```
<Buffer ff fe 3d 00 3d 00 3d 00 20 00 56 00 65 00 72 00 62 00 6f 00 73 00 65 00 20 00 6c 00 6f 00 67 00 67 00 69 00 6e 00 67 00 20 00 73 00 74 00 61 00 72 00 ... >
```

**Sometimes the blob is provided as a LOB:**

```
Lob {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { end: { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function: onend] },
     finish: { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function] } },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState:
   WritableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     finalCalled: false,
     needDrain: false,
     ending: false,
     ended: false,
     finished: false,
     destroyed: false,
     decodeStrings: true,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     length: 0,
     writing: false,
     corked: 0,
     sync: true,
     bufferProcessing: false,
     onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
     writecb: null,
     writelen: 0,
     bufferedRequest: null,
     lastBufferedRequest: null,
     pendingcb: 0,
     prefinished: false,
     errorEmitted: false,
     bufferedRequestCount: 0,
     corkedRequestsFree:
      { next: null,
        entry: null,
        finish: [Function: bound onCorkedFinish] } },
  writable: true,
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  iLob:
   ILob {
     valid: true,
     autoCloseLob: true,
     type: 2007,
     offset: 1,
     pieceSize: 8060,
     length: 1062462,
     chunkSize: 8060 },
  close: [Function] }
```

Comment: What is the type of the column? Is there a size at which below it returns a Buffer and above it returns a LOB?

Comment: The data type of the column is a Blob.

Comment: You make a good point about the size at which it may return a Buffer vs a LOB.  I will experiment.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior isn't random. As [stated in the doc](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#typemap), both BLOBs and CLOBs are returned as instances of the Lob class. That class implements the [Node.js stream interface](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html). This is necessary for larger LOBs so you're not buffering everything in Node.js. See the section of the doc on [streaming LOBs](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-153-streaming-lobs) for more info.

See these examples too:

- https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/lobstream1.js
- https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/lobstream2.js

For folks that are working with relatively smaller LOBs (say a few megabytes or less) and/or smaller numbers of end users, the overhead of the stream API isn't worth it. For those folks, fetching the LOB from the database fully materialized as either a Buffer (for BLOBs) for as a String (for CLOBs) is much easier.

In those cases, the driver offers several options to override the defaults:

1. [oracledb.fetchAsBuffer](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propdbfetchasbuffer): This is a global setting that will affect all queries. This can be used to specify that BLOBs should be fetched as Buffers.
2. [oracldb.fetchAsString](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-329-oracledbfetchasstring): This is another global setting that will affect all queries. It can be used to specify that CLOBs should be fetched as Strings.
3. [fetchInfo](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#--42634-fetchinfo): This is an `execute` option that will only affect the query being executed. It's an object with "column to type" mapping details.

See this example of fetchInfo:

- https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/fetchinfo.js

Comment: I am dealing with files that are 4MB or less.  But, I can request the same file from the database multiple times and sometimes it returns the data as a LOB for which I can listen for events via "on".  Other times it returns the data as a buffer  when listening for events using "on" results in errors stating "On" is not a method.